# Algoritmo com fluxograma/diagrama

Tags: arquivo, algoritmo, diagrama

Galera, estou fazendo uma curso de lógica e caiu a seguinte questão:

> Elabore um diagrama de blocos para verificar que produtos precisam ser comprados e a quantidade a ser adquirida: Tendo as seguintes informações:
>
> - Código do produto (CODPRO), Quantidade mínima (QTDMIN), Quantidade máxima (QTDMAX) e a quantidade em estoque (QTDEST) de cada produto.
> - Um produto somente deverá ser comprado quando: a quantidade em estoque for menor ou igual a quantidade mínima: QTDCOMPRA = (QTDMAX – QTDEST)
> - Grave em outro arquivo: Código do produto e Quantidade a Comprar

Fiz assim, e gostaria de saber se estou mais ou menos no rumo certo ou completamente fora do rumo e por quê?

[image: diagrama]

Comment: Não confunda "*lógica*" com "*lógica de programação*". São coisas diferentes.

Comment: Isso daí é para ser um fluxograma?

Comment: Não entendi as comparações com `X` se ele é apenas o código do produto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Além dos problemas informados na primeira resposta, este diagrama mostra de como seria o fluxo das comparações, onde `NÃO` quer dizer que uma das comparações não foram atendidas, portanto válidas, e `SIM` que foram atendidas, não são válidas.

No caso `(k > z)  ou  (k < y)  ou  (k > w)`, quer dizer, respectivamente:

- `(k > z)`: a quantidade de compra é maior que a quantidade máxima;
- `(k < y)`: a quantidade de compra é menor que a quantidade mínima, e
- `(k > w)`: a quantidade de compra é maior que a quantidade no estoque.

O `Se não x (EOF) ou x (EOF)` verifica se o código do produto existe ou não existe.

```
codpro = x;
qtdmin = y;
qtdmax = z;
qtdest = w;
qtdcompra = k;

         Se não x (EOF)    ou    x (EOF)
              |                     |
---------------------------------   |
(k > z)  ou  (k < y)  ou  (k > w)   |
---------------------------------   |
          |    |                    |
         NÃO  SIM--------           |
          |             |           |
      [COMPRAR]   [NÃO COMPRAR]------
          |             |
        [FIM]------------
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Agora eu fiz assim:

 [![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0m3H9.jpg


Melhorou ou não fez diferença?
O que vocês acham?

Comment: @HernaneMendes Só use o campo "resposta" para colocar uma resposta que responda à pergunta. Se quiser uma fazer uma nova pergunta, utilize o botão "perguntar". Abs!

Answer (score 1):

Seu fluxograma está bastante confuso e errado. O único losango que vejo, onde uma decisão deve ser tomada é no "*`Se EOF`*". Entretanto, abaixo dele não há duas linhas "*`Sim`*" e "*`Não`*" saindo. Mas nas caixas abaixo, que como retângulos deveriam representar instruções/atribuições, há um monte de "*`Sim`*"s e "*`Não`*"s saindo para vários lados.

Observe por exemplo a caixa do "*`X > Y`*". Há duas arestas escrito "`Não`" indo a ela, e como não há setinhas, não dá para se saber qual eu deveria escolher.

Visto que "*`CODPRO`*" é "*`X`*" e "*`QTDMAX`*" é "*`Z`*", a caixinha "*`X <= Z`*" quer dizer "*`CODPRO <= QTDMAX`*". Ora, não tem sentido comparar o código de um produto com a quantidade desse produto. As demais caixinhas "*`X > Y`*", "*`X <= Y`*" e "*`X == Z`*" também fazem o mesmo tipo de operação sem sentido. A única que está no caminho certo é o "*`K = Z - W`*".

Além disso, o seu algoritmo não escreve no arquivo, apenas usa o "*`Se EOF`*" como se tivesse que ler dele.

Ficar renomeando variáveis como você fez é uma péssima prática de programação e só serve para causar confusão, inclusive parece que você confundiu a si mesmo. Se não tivesse inventado isso de que "*`CODPRO`*" é "*`X`*" e "*`QTDMAX`*" é "*`Z`*", você não teria escrito "*`X <= Z`*".

E também, o que é aquele "*`Não comprar`*"? Uma caixa escrito "*`Comprar`*" até faria sentido como uma ação a ser feita, mas uma etapa do algoritmo especificando o que não é para fazer não tem sentido nenhum. Além disso, o seu algoritmo não deveria comprar ou deixar de comprar nada, deveria é gravar uma informação no arquivo.

Desculpe-me a sinceridade, mas isso que você fez está completamente errado. Pode jogar isso tudo fora e recomeçar com uma folha em branco.

Comment: Ahhh sim! Tudo bem, não me importo pela sinceridade, na verdade eu gostaria de agradecê-lo. Muito obrigado! Tentarei novamente e qualquer coisa jogo aqui de novo!

Comment: Agora eu fiz assim:

 [![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0m3H9.jpg


Melhorou ou não fez diferença?
O que vocês acham?